# Fetching data from table using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, oracle11g

I am able to persist objects in relational database using hibernate. 
        please look at following code.

```
package one;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SecondaryTable;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private int customerId;
    private String customerName;
    private String customerAddress;
    private int creditScore;
    private int rewardPoints;

    public Customer()
    {

    }

    public Customer(int customerId,String customerName,String customerAddress,int creditScore,int rewardsPoints)
    {
        this.customerId=customerId;
        this.customerAddress=customerAddress;
        this.creditScore=creditScore;
        this.customerName=customerName;
        this.rewardPoints=rewardsPoints;
    }

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }
    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }


    public String getCustomerAddress() {
        return customerAddress;
    }
    public void setCustomerAddress(String customerAddress) {
        this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
    }


    public int getCreditScore() {
        return creditScore;
    }
    public void setCreditScore(int creditScore) {
        this.creditScore = creditScore;
    }

    public int getRewardPoints() {
        return rewardPoints;
    }
    public void setRewardPoints(int rewardPoints) {
        this.rewardPoints = rewardPoints;
    }

}
```

Then to save object of this class i used following class. following class creates the object of class Customer and saves that object in database then again retrieves it and prints the CustomerName property of every saved object.

```
package one;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TestCustomer {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer(13,"Sara","Banglore",9000,60);


        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(cust);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        session = factory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List list = session.createQuery("FROM Customer").list();
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator();

        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Customer custA = (Customer)iterator.next();
            System.out.println("First Name\t"+custA.getCustomerName());
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }
}
```

I executed above code quite a number of times. code is running fine. it is able to fetch all objects which are saved. 
but then i used oracle toad and fired a `sql` statement as

```
Insert into Customer(CUSTOMERID,CREDITSCORE,CUSTOMERNAME,REWARDPOINTS,CUSTOMERADDRESS)
VALUES(87,4000,'Saurabh',20,'Kalwa');
```

record gets stored in the table but when i execute above code, i am not able to fetch this record. 
one conclusion i can draw is hibernate only returns `persisted objects`, but still is there any other way i can get all records ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you sure you have submitted the record after inserting with toad for oracle?(you can open another client and execute a select to make sure it can be fetched from sql client).
2. If you want to debug, you can enable the sql logging function of hibernate, and then execute the sql which hibernate generates for your query in a sql client to make sure all the records can be fetched correctly.

And some suggestions for using JPA:

1. Make sure the @Entity has a name value which mapping to your physical table to avoid table mapping confusion.
2. Use @Column(name="column") for all your fields to mapping to the physical table column to avoid confusion.

Comment: Looks like the first is the reason. _suggestions for using JPA_ is not a mandatory.  Using a naming strategy is a good practice.